# Stepwise regression in r with mixed models: numbers of rows changing

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, lmertest

Employing the `lmerTest` package in `r`, I am using the syntax below to run a stepwise selection on a mixed model containing 2 continuous predictors (`Duration`, `PrevSegDuration`), 1 categorical factor (`PrevSeg`), and 1 random effect factor (`Respondent`).

```
m1 <- lmer(TotalCount ~ Duration + PrevSeg + PrevSegDuration + (1|Respondent), d1) 
step.m1 <- step(m1, reduce.random=FALSE)
```

After successfully completing the full model, the following error appears without completing the step:

`Error: number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?`

I am not sure what may cause the issue, though I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817564/stepwise-regression-error-in-r) similar issue with steps in linear models may be relevant. Any insights into how `step` may lead to changes in the number of rows in a reduced model would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the answer in the linked question? I'd think it is the same issue here.

Comment: Re-checking my data, I found some previously unidentified missing values.  The issue noted in the linked question indeed seemed to be the same issue here, as `step` now completes fine with those NAs now addressed. Thanks.